# SFML - Creating a cursor and printing input?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, sfml, tdm-mingw

So I've downloaded SFML and so far love it. I've run into a roadblock and am trying to figure out how to implement a blinking cursor into the code below. I also need to figure out how to print a single char (when the user presses a key on the keyboard) onto the window. Here's some code I've used ever since I've downloaded SFML 2.0:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow wnd(sf::VideoMode(650, 300), "SFML Console");
    sf::Vector2u myVector(650, 300);
    wnd.setSize(myVector);

    sf::Font myFont;
    myFont.loadFromFile("theFont.ttf");

    sf::Color myClr;
    myClr.r = 0;
    myClr.g = 203;
    myClr.b = 0;

    sf::String myStr = "Hello world!";
    std::char myCursor = '_';

    sf::Text myTxt;
    myTxt.setColor(myClr);
    myTxt.setString(myStr);
    myTxt.setFont(myFont);
    myTxt.setCharacterSize(12);
    myTxt.setStyle(sf::Text::Regular);
    myTxt.setPosition(0, 0);

    std::int myCounter = 0;

    while(wnd.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event myEvent;

        while (wnd.pollEvent(myEvent)) {
            if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                wnd.close();
            }

            if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (myEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                    wnd.close();
                }
            }

            wnd.clear();
            wnd.draw(myTxt);

            myCounter++;
            std::if (myCounter >= 1000) {
                myCounter = 0;
            }

            std::if (myCounter < 1000) {
                myTxt.setString("Hello world!_");
            }

            wnd.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sf::Clock` ([doc](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/system-time.php)).

Declare your clock along with your other variables before your main loop, this also starts the clock automatically. In your loop, check for the time elapsed and reset the clock if it exceeds what you want. Example :

```
sf::Clock myClock; // starts the clock
bool showCursor = false;

// ...

wnd.draw(myTxt);

if(clock.getElapsedTime() >= sf::milliseconds(500))
{
    clock.restart();
    showCursor = !showCursor;
    if(showCursor)
        myTxt.setString("Hello World!_");
    else
        myTxt.setString("Hello World!");
}

// ...
```

This should give you a cursor blinking by 0.5 second.

By the way, why are you using `std::if()` instead of a plain `if` that is included in the language ?

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now. Oh, the std::if was a simple mistake, and I've replaced it with a normal if.

Comment: Uhm, I've just tested my code with your example, and apparently I need to have the mouse constantly moving over the SFML screen for the cursor to blink. Is there a way to have the cursor blink without me having to move the mouse in a constant way to have the cursor blink? Here's the source: http://pastebin.com/VjBNgpPC

Comment: @Mike The `}` closing your `while (wnd.pollEvent(myEvent)) {` is misplaced. It should be closed just after you tested the events (that is, line 45 in pastebin). Right now your code is run only when there are events for your window and that's why you need to move your mouse. Another thing, you should place the `if(showCursor)/else` inside the `if` that's testing elapsed time: you only need to change the text to draw once when the time exceeds 500ms, not at every frame.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for that. So this program is supposed to imitate a console window. For my next question, should a start a new question, or ask it on this one?